# Scala, ZIO - log something after every retry

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, zio

I have a simple code which do `retry` when publishing message failed:

```
eventPublisher.publish(someData)
.retry(Schedule.recurs(5))
.fold(
_ => ZIO.succeed(logger.error(s"Publishing failed")),
_ => ZIO.succeed(logger.info(s"Publishing succeeded"))
)
```

But I am not sure if it would log error after every `retry`.
I would like to log "Publishing event failed" after every retry if publishing failed.
Also I am not sure if the code after `retry` (`fold` one I mean) is performed after every `retry` cycle.

Is it correct approach or I should use something else to reach what I need?

Comment: You want to publish 5 times even if the first one succeeds ?

Comment: If it succeed in the meantime I want to log that it succeed. But if it fails for example 3 times, I want log 3 times that it failed.

Answer (score 2):

You build your computations as values, and how you build values tell you how it will be used:

```
eventPublisher.publish(someData)
  .retry(Schedule.recurs(5))
  .fold(
    _ => ZIO.succeed(logger.error(s"Publishing failed")),
    _ => ZIO.succeed(logger.info(s"Publishing succeeded"))
  ) // IO[IO[PublishError, Unit]]
```

is the same as (referential transparency)

```
val retriedPublish = eventPublisher.publish(someData).retry(Schedule.recurs(5))

retriedPublish.fold(
  _ => ZIO.succeed(logger.error(s"Publishing failed")),
  _ => ZIO.succeed(logger.info(s"Publishing succeeded"))
)
```

so I would expect it to log once, after (at most) 5 attempts. To achieve the opposite I would apply the operations in reverse order (something like)

```
eventPublisher.publish(someData)
  .fold(
    _ => ZIO.succeed(logger.error(s"Publishing failed")),
    _ => ZIO.succeed(logger.info(s"Publishing succeeded"))
  ) // IO[IO[PublishError, Unit]] !!!
  .flatten
  .retry(Schedule.recurs(5))
```

This is same as (again referential transparency)

```
val loggedPublish = eventPublisher.publish(someData)
  .fold(
    _ => ZIO.succeed(logger.error(s"Publishing failed")),
    _ => ZIO.succeed(logger.info(s"Publishing succeeded"))
  )
  .flatten

loggedPublish.retry(Schedule.recurs(5))
```

Your `.fold` however recovers errors so we should so something like this to obtain the expected behavior (not loosing failure information)

```
eventPublisher.publish(someData)
  .fold(
    error => ZIO.succeed(logger.error(s"Publishing failed")) andThen ZIO.fail(error),
    _ => ZIO.succeed(logger.info(s"Publishing succeeded"))
  )
  .flatten
  .retry(Schedule.recurs(5))
  // whether you want to recover after 5 failures is up to you
```

Comment: It looks logically. Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: I just made a small update so take it into consideration

Comment: I think your last 3 examples cannot compile in ZIO. Looks like cannot `fold` cannot be use before `retry`. Error msg: "This error handling operation assumes your effect can fail. However, your effect has Nothing for the error type, which means it cannot fail, so there is no need to handle the failure."

Comment: What is the signature of `eventPublisher.publish(someData)`?

Comment: `IO[PublishError, Unit]`

Comment: `.fold` is not flattening, while we mapped values inside into IO. Try now.

Comment: One more question about `andThen ZIO.fail(error)`. Do I need it if I only want to log every time it fails? I just do not want to break after first fail

Comment: You need it, or your `.fold` will recover from the failure and `.retry` will have no error to retry on. Then you would log once, and you would not make another attempt to publish.